# Best way to get all sets of combinations from string by a letter or pair in python

Tags: python, combinations

How do I get all possible set of combinations from a given string?  Where a set can be a letter or a pair (next to each other).  For example,

```
"abc" = 
a, b, c
ab, c
a, bc
```

or

```
"abcd" = 
a, b, c, d
ab, c, d
a, bc, d
a, b, cd
ab, cd
```

For the above, was thinking of generating something like

```
1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
1 0 1 0
```

where '1' means its by itself and '1 0' means its together.  Where two '0' cannot be next to each other and '0' cannot be on the first item.  Can possibly be done with recursion but can get confusing.  And Im not sure if its really the right way to approach the problem.

Was wondering if there is an itertools function that I can use?  If not, what would be the best approach to get the solution?

Comment: @Julien: This is not all combinations -- just singles and pairs.  However, the link would be helpful in getting a solution.

Comment: Have you tried creating a function that takes a string, iterates over the length of the sting, and returns a list containing each char and each pair? That should be a few lines of code that you can feed into itertools.combinations.

Comment: I think you can do something with restricted partitions  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_partitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not this simple recursive approach?

```
def sets(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        return [list(s)]
    return [[s[0]]+x for x in sets(s[1:])] + [[s[:2]]+x for x in sets(s[2:])]

sets('abcd')
```

gives:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'cd'],
 ['a', 'bc', 'd'],
 ['ab', 'c', 'd'],
 ['ab', 'cd']]
```

Explanation: to partition your string into singlets or pairs, the first letter is either alone (first list with `s[0]`) or coupled with the second letter (second list with `s[:2]`), you then need to complete the set by partitioning the remaining of the string: for each set on the remaining of the list: prepend the first element.

Comment: This simple yet awesome solution is definitely what I was looking for.  Care to explain how this works? I mean I can read your code but just wondering how you came up with the solution.  Like your logic of thinking lol

Comment: I think its clear enough.  Will spend some more time learning your techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that avoids recursion. It fingerprints all possible partitions by listing the start indices of pairs. If m is the length of the input string then all such fingerprints for *k* pairs can be constructed by

- finding all `itertools.combination`s of *k* out of *m*-*k* and then
- adding 1 to the second position, 2 to the third 3 to the fourth and so on

code:

```
m = 'abcdef'
fp = [[l+i for i, l in enumerate(c)] for k in range(len(m) // 2 + 1) for c in it.combinations(range(len(m)-k), k)]
fp
# [[], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [0, 2, 4]]
[list(m)] + [list(m[:f[0]]) + sum([[m[i:i+2]] + list(m[i+2:j]) for i, j in zip(f,f[1:] + [len(m)])], []) for f in fp[1:]]
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['ab', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'bc', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
   ['a', 'b', 'cd', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'de', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ef'],
   ['ab', 'cd', 'e', 'f'], ['ab', 'c', 'de', 'f'], ['ab', 'c', 'd', 'ef'], ['a', 'bc', 'de', 'f'],
   ['a', 'bc', 'd', 'ef'], ['a', 'b', 'cd', 'ef'], ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which uses a recursive generator.

The arg to `gen` is a list of strings. It scans through the list looking for adjacent pairs of single letter strings and joins them into pairs.

```
def gen(seq, lo=0):
    yield seq
    for i in range(lo, len(seq) - 1):
        u, v = seq[i:i+2]
        if len(u) == 1 == len(v):
            yield from gen(seq[:i] + [u + v] + seq[i+2:], i + 1)

src = 'abcde'
for s in gen(list(src)):
    print(s)
```

**output**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['ab', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['ab', 'cd', 'e']
['ab', 'c', 'de']
['a', 'bc', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'bc', 'de']
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'de']
```

To run this code on Python 2 replace the `yield from` statement with a `for` loop, eg:

```
for item in gen(seq[:i] + [u + v] + seq[i+2:], i + 1):
    yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a cute adaptation of stronger programming problems.  You need a double recursion.  In many such problems, you want to find *all* partitions or combinations of the string; in this case, you want only the first two.

The critical part is something like this, for an input string **str**:

```
result1 = my_func(str[1:])
result2 = my_func(str[2:])
```

For each result, you need to pre-pend the letter or letters you excluded from the front, to each returned sequence.

That, combined with your research on recursive algorithms, should get you moving toward a solution.